# Simple model error on fit: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, data-science

I know this question exists in various forms, but after searching the web for several days/hours, I still havent found anything, that solved my problem.

This is my notebook:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

X = pd.read_csv('../input/web-traffic-time-series-forecasting/train_1.csv.zip')
X = X.drop('Page', axis=1)
X.fillna(0, inplace=True, axis=0)

X_sliced = X.iloc[:, 0:367]
y_sliced = X.iloc[:, 367:-1]

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

linreg = LinearRegression()

X_sliced.drop(X_sliced.iloc[:, 182:367], inplace=True, axis=1) #Here, I make sure that my X_sliced has the same shape as y_sliced

X_sliced.shape
```

OUT: (145063, 182)

```
y_sliced.shape
```

OUT: (145063, 182)

```
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X_sliced, y_sliced)
linreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

**ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [108797, 36266]**

Why do I receive this error, when the shape of my dataframes are completely the same?

Link to original assignment on kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/c/web-traffic-time-series-forecasting/overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've assigned the outputs of `train_test_split` in the wrong order, it should be:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_sliced, y_sliced) # x, x, y, y not x, y, x, y
```