# Append two dataframes and create a new

Tags: python, pandas

I have made a simple model, fitted, predicted and scored on it for an (old) competition on Kaggle. Now I want to make a submission.

I have cut out any code, that I deem unneccessary to solve this problem:

```
sample_sub = pd.read_csv('../input/web-traffic-time-series-forecasting/sample_submission_1.csv.zip')

key_1 = pd.read_csv('../input/web-traffic-time-series-forecasting/key_1.csv.zip')

pages_and_id = sample_sub.append(key_1, ignore_index=True)

pages_and_id.drop('Page', axis=1, inplace=True)

pages_and_id.fillna(0)

pages_and_id.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

submission = pd.DataFrame(index=pages_and_id['Id'], data=predictions, columns=pages_and_id['Visits']) #predictions is simply the variable made earlier, when predicting on the model
```

The last line results in this error:

**ValueError: Shape of passed values is (36266, 182), indices imply (17407560, 17407560)**

Link to original assignment on kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/c/web-traffic-time-series-forecasting/overview

Comment: Can you please provide your predictions? I can't run your code without it

Comment: @BrunoMello Thanks a lot for looking into it. Here is my code and how I generated predictions from a previous question I asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60927250/simple-model-error-on-fit-found-input-variables-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-sa

Comment: pages_and_id simply do not have the same length as predictions. Without raw data it is impossible pinpoint the problem.

Comment: @Sikan Thanks for commenting. The raw data is available at the Kaggle competition. I have provided the link for that by the end of my original post.

Comment: @above_c_level Did you have a chance to take a look at the raw data?